# Merge every two consecutive txt files in folder - Python

Tags: python, merge

```
import glob
import os
filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')  # list of all .txt files in the directory

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for file in filenames:
        with open(file) as infile:
            filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            f.write("<s>+"infile.read()+"</s>"+filename)
```

I found this script for merging every txt in folder but I don't know how to access *next file* in filenames list. I have merged file but since I add notation for every line I refused to merge that file and instead try to do it before.

EDIT: e.g.

I have File1.txt, File2.txt, File3.txt,... I want in File1 = File1 + File2, File2 = File3 + File4

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you want to skip a file can you use continue inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']
```

You can do:

```
for f1, f2 in zip(filenames[0:-1:2], filenames[1::2]):
    print(f1, f2)
    # do your operations here
```

and you will get:

```
# iteration 1
file1.txt file2.txt
# iteration 2
file3.txt file4.txt
```

However if you have odd number of files, the last one won't be reached